# What is difference between these FormData constructors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made project in PHP or JavaScript. However in this project I faced one problem. I don't know about this:

```
var formData = new FormData();

// and:

var form  = getElementById('myform');
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

```html
<form action="#" id="myform" method="post">
  <input type='hidden' name='redirect_to' value='34' />
  <input type='text' name='test' />
  <input type='submit' value='Test form' />
</form>
```

Will this code give me difference result?

Comment: The first returns you an empty FormData object. The second provides the FormData constructor with a reference to a `form` element, so it gets filled with the data in that form. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for more information about this. Do you have a specific issue with the code?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'. at addImageOfProject (test.php?index=0:2763)
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick



I got this error in console. when i tried  this: var form  = getElementById('myform');
var formData = new FormData(form);

Comment: `getElementById('myform');` -> `document.getElementById('myform');`

Comment: Sorry this is only typing  mistake actually  I am also trying "document.getElementById('myform')". But error is same

Comment: In that case the `form` element is not being found in the DOM. There's either a typo, multiple elements with the same `id`, or you're running your JS before the DOM has loaded. We'd need a more complete example of your code to diagnose that

Comment: Yes, i agree with your opinion.  May be same "id: problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new `FormData()` object will instantiate an empty FormData object that you can manually populate with the relevant information. For example, you could do:

```
let foo = new FormData();
let bar = document.querySelector('input')

// Add bar to form data
foo.append(bar.name, bar.value);
```

This allows you to include only the data you choose in a form post.

If you pass a form in as an argument to `FormData` (as above, with `new FormData(form)`) then your `FormData` object will be pre-populated with all of the data from the arguments provided (e.g. `form`). This means that if you want everything within the form to be posted, you can simply pass it through in one go.

In both instances, you can use `append()` and `delete()` to add/remove additional information to the `FormData` object.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'. at addImageOfProject (test.php?index=0:2763)
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick



I got this error in console. when i tried  this: var form  = getElementById('myform');
var formData = new FormData(form);

Comment: You have a typo - change `getElementById('myform')` to `document.getElementById('myform')` - you need a root reference to search from to find an element by its ID - in this case, `document`

Comment: Sorry this is only typing  mistake actually  I am also trying "document.getElementById('myform')". But error is same.

Comment: Then the problem is not from the code snippets you shared, unfortunately. I have created a fiddle and it shows no errors: https://jsfiddle.net/e6zn03fb/